# I'm trying to remove the last two characters from my results

Tags: sql, db2

I am running into a problem when I pull in the city name from my database that includes the 2 character state abbreviation at the very end.

Examples

```
CITY
WELLSBURG WV
FRANKFORT NY
ORANGE TX
```

I thought I could fix the problem by using the following SUBSTR function, but the table holds 27 characters which adds spaces at the end of each string to fill the 27 character requirement.  Therefore, I'm not able to use the function because the spaces at the end of each result varies.

```
SUBSTR(S.CITY_NAME, 1, LENGTH(S.CITY_NAME)-2) AS "CITY"
```

I appreciate any suggestions to get around this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the `RTRIM`, `LTRIM` and `TRIM` functions and use it to remove the spaces at at the end each word. Something like this:

```
SUBSTR(TRIM(S.CITY_NAME), 1, LENGTH(TRIM(S.CITY_NAME))-2) AS "CITY"
```

Check [this link](http://srinimf.com/2012/07/04/db2-sql-ltrim-rtrim-and-trim/) for more details.

Comment: Grrrrr.  I tried that at first but only used trim on the front end.  It never dawned on me to use trim on the back end as well.  This worked perfectly.  Thank you, sir!

Comment: I have to wait so many minutes before accepting the answer.  I will try again in 8 minutes when it will let me.

Comment: Does every city name have the state in it?

Comment: @Charles Yes, they all have the state at the end